# Anyone either read japanese or know about laying tracks for a micro SD card slot?

Tags: pcb, connector, surface-mount, sd

I'm trying to include a micro SD card slot in a project I'm working on and I'm having a little trouble with the datasheet. 
Unfortunately I don't read japanese.

Just wondering what the text says in the 3 Shaded boxes on page 2:

[image]

https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/5031821852_sd.pdf

Can I run PCB tracks under the shaded region back to my processor?

Comment: Now I wonder what パターン is supposed to be. "Part" doesn't quite fit.

Comment: I remember having had to guess that exact same thing... I don't clearly remember what my conclusions were, though. Certainly something along the lines of "Damn molex, lemme get that from another manufacturer"...

Comment: @SimonRichter "パターン" is "pattern".

Comment: Wherever possible, it's best to have the physical part in hand when you're designing the board.  In theory the data sheet should be enough.  In practice, even without a language issue, you're better off with the sum awareness of what the vendor wrote, and what you can see with your own eyes.

Comment: By the way there is a Japanese language stack exchange https://japanese.stackexchange.com/ where there might people who can help

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Google translate on your phone can do this:
[image]

- Parts prohibited area (部品搭軾禁止エリア)
- Pattern prohibited area (パターン禁止エリア)
- Soldering prohibited area (半田付け禁止エリア)

Comment: So in other words: "Keepout"...

Comment: How do you know what phone the OP has?

Comment: @PlasmaHH phone isn't really relevant.  Web google translate will do it too - there's a handwriting input method so you can just write the characters in and it will translate them.  Getting the [stroke order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroke_order) mostly correct is all you really need to know there.

Comment: @J... lol if the OP doesn't know Japanese, how in the world do you think they'll be able to get the stroke order correct?  I'm learning Japanese and I'd still be guessing.

Comment: @BenSandeen It's not that hard - you can learn the basics in less time than it takes to read a data sheet.

Comment: @PlasmaHH  What makes you think he knows what phone the OP has?

Comment: https://translate.yandex.com will, too, I believe. Its web version accepts images. Web google translate can also work on images. You can feed it screenshots instead of rewriting Japanese.

Answer (score 19):

Disclaimer: I am clueless about EE, but read Japanese well enough to look this up.

Black box: 部品搭載禁止エリア = "components/parts-loading prohibited area" (don't put stuff here, I assume).

Diagonal lines: パターン禁止エリア = "Pattern prohibited area" (I don't know what "pattern" refers to in this context, but don't do it there).

Diamond box: 半田付け禁止エリア = "solder-attaching prohibited area" (don't solder anything here). 半田 (handa) is "solder" in case you see that elsewhere.

Comment: "Pattern" possibly "traces?"

Comment: @AliChen Thanks for the correction, you correct! It seems likely to me the word "pattern" here refers to the [land pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footprint_(electronics)) aka the footprint. [This spec sheet](https://www.marutsu.co.jp/contents/shop/marutsu/datasheet/UX60A-MB-5ST.pdf), for instance,  refers to it both as パータン and ランドパターン.

Answer (score 14):

In this micro-SD socket the spring contacts are located at the bottom of footprint, and during card insertion they may touch the PCB surface. Therefore there is a chance that PCB protective layer will be compromised over time, and the contacts will touch traces, if any. Therefore the manufacturer recommends to leave the shaded area without routing any signal traces or ground pours.

The black area is around the insertion detect contact, which moves sideways, so keep other components out of that area.